# How can I hide emails marked as done in a bundle in Inbox by Gmail?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I created a bundle in Inbox by Gmail. In this bundle I would like to only display emails that are not yet marked as done. Emails marked as done should not be displayed, respectively.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot of a bundle]

Comment: Please show what you found when you did your research before posting the question and your progress to find the solution. See [ask] for further details.

Comment: **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

Use `in:inbox` search keyword to "hide" messages marked as done.

## Explanation

You could search for mails in a bundle by using the in: operator followed by the bundle name in similar way that this is done for labels in Gmail.

Messages undone are in the Inbox, messages done are removed from the inbox.

The bundle shown in the screenshot is SCORAI. To show messages in SCORAI bundle that are not done use the following search keywords:

```
in:SCORAI in:inbox
```

## References

- [How Inbox works with Gmail](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6098273?hl=en)
- [Clean up your inbox with bundles](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6050237?hl=en)

Comment: It appears your example is incorrect. When I test with my own account, I find that `in:some-bundle -in:inbox` returns only DONE messages for that bundle, whereas `in:some-bundle in:inbox` returns messages not yet marked as DONE for that bundle.

Comment: @JonL. You are right.